# Adding custom validation to Kendo Grid display?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, rest, typescript

We have an internal tool that we're using to bulk add users to our database. To do this, a user will upload a CSV file that is read client-side and displayed in a Kendo Grid.

I'm trying to implement some form of validation that would push the collection to the web service and return the validated collection, showing what fields need to be corrected, and which ones are valid.

Currently the object is structured like the following:

```
export interface IBulkUserObject {
    FirstName: string;
    GlobalLogin: string;
    JobTitle?: string;
    LastName: string;
    Organization?: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
}
```

Essentially I need to figure out how to do basic validation on this object. Obviously it's pretty simple to get this information to and from the client, but I'm not entirely sure how to denote which fields are valid and which aren't and then pass this information to the kendo grid.

```
this.fullGrid = $("#verifyGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: this.gridData,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "GlobalLogin",
                fields: {
                    Organization: { type: "string" },
                    GlobalLogin: { type: "string" },
                    FirstName: { type: "string" },
                    LastName: { type: "string" },
                    PhoneNumber: { type: "string" },
                    JobTitle: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 100
    },
    height: 650,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false
    },
    columns: [
        { command: ["edit"], width: "100px" },
        {
            field: "Organization",
            title: "Organization",
            width: "200px"
        },
        {
            field: "GlobalLogin",
            title: "Global Login",
            width: "200px"
        },
        {
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name",
            width: "200px"
        },
        {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name",
            width: "200px"
        },
        {
            field: "PhoneNumber",
            title: "Phone Number",
            width: "200px"
        },
        {
            field: "JobTitle",
            title: "Job Title",
            width: "200px"
        }
    ],
    editable: "inline",
    save() {
        alert("edited");
    }
});
```

---

### Edit

Posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've been playing around with this for most of the day, and I believe I've come up with something that somewhat works, but I'm not sure if there's a better method.

I modified my initial object structure to be the following:

```
export interface IBulkUserObjectTest {
    Email?: string;
    FirstName: IVerificationProperty<string>;
    GlobalLogin: IVerificationProperty<string>;
    JobTitle?: IVerificationProperty<string>;
    LastName: IVerificationProperty<string>;
    Organization?: IVerificationProperty<string>;
    PhoneNumber: IVerificationProperty<string>;
}

export interface IVerificationProperty<T> {
    Value?: T;
    Valid: boolean;
    VerificationMessage?: string;
}
```

However, since my CSV still produced a flat object, I needed to shape the data, so I created a method of doing that:

```
private shapeGridData = (data: Array<Models.IBulkUserObject>): Array<Models.IBulkUserObjectTest> => {
    var newItems: Array<Models.IBulkUserObjectTest> = new Array();
    data.forEach(item => {
        var newItem: Models.IBulkUserObjectTest = {
            Organization: { Value: item.Organization, Valid: true },
            GlobalLogin: { Value: item.GlobalLogin, Valid: true },
            Email: item.GlobalLogin,
            FirstName: { Value: item.FirstName, Valid: true },
            LastName: { Value: item.LastName, Valid: true },
            PhoneNumber: { Value: item.PhoneNumber, Valid: true },
            JobTitle: { Value: item.JobTitle, Valid: true }
        };
        newItems.push(newItem);
    });

    return newItems;
}
```

Now Kendo grid really seems to hate complex objects, so that took some serious tweaking.

```
this.fullGrid = $("#verifyGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: this.gridDataVerified,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Email",
                fields: {
                    Email: { },
                    GlobalLogin: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }],
                    Organization: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }],
                    FirstName: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }],
                    LastName: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }],
                    PhoneNumber: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }],
                    CompanyName: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }],
                    JobTitle: [{ Value: { type: "string" }, Valid: { type: "boolean" } }]
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 100
    },
    height: 650,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false
    },
    columns: [
        { command: ["edit"], width: "100px" },
        {
            field: "GlobalLogin",
            title: "Global Login",
            width: "200px",
            template: "<span #= GlobalLogin.Valid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#=GlobalLogin.Value#</span>",
            editor(container, options) {
                el.kendoEditor(container, options);
            }
            //template: "<span #= GlobalLoginValid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#: GlobalLogin #</span>"
        },
        {
            field: "Organization",
            title: "Organization",
            width: "200px",
            template: "<span #= Organization.Valid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#=Organization.Value#</span>",
            editor(container, options) {
                el.kendoEditor(container, options);
            }
        },
        {
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name",
            width: "200px",
            template: "<span #= FirstName.Valid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#=FirstName.Value#</span>",
            editor(container, options) {
                el.kendoEditor(container, options);
            }
        },
        {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name",
            width: "200px",
            template: "<span #= LastName.Valid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#=LastName.Value#</span>",
            editor(container, options) {
                el.kendoEditor(container, options);
            }
        },
        {
            field: "PhoneNumber",
            title: "Phone Number",
            width: "200px",
            template: "<span #= PhoneNumber.Valid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#=PhoneNumber.Value#</span>",
            editor(container, options) {
                el.kendoEditor(container, options);
            }
        },
        {
            field: "JobTitle",
            title: "Job Title",
            width: "200px",
            template: "<span #= JobTitle.Valid ? \"\" : 'class=\"errorClass\"' #>#=JobTitle.Value#</span>",
            editor(container, options) {
                el.kendoEditor(container, options);
            }
        }
    ],
    editable: "inline",
    save() {
        alert("Postback");
    }
});
```

Finally, I had to fix the editor so that it knew what I was editing and where, so I created a function to do just that.

```
private kendoEditor = (container, options) => {
    var input = $("<input/>");
    input.attr("name", options.field + ".Value");
    input.appendTo(container);
    input.addClass("k-input k-textbox");
}
```